# Warm reboot directly to Grub

Tags: reboot, bios

Is it possible to warm-reboot Linux, directly reloading GRUB without passing through the BIOS? I have a computer whose BIOS is buggy and takes a while due to its hating my disks so if I can reboot directly to Grub it would be great.

To those that are confused: I'm looking for is a kernel module that acts to unload the kernel and execute the boot sector upon a "reboot".

Here are my system specs:

Emachines el1200-06w with an AMD athlon 64

- [`dmidecode` output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1049808/)
- [`lspci` output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1049813/)

Comment: Sounds interesting... Might be possible in linux world, but seems to be tricky for you gonna skip a major step (BIOS) which dictates the booting order and initialize it.. Try updating the bios instead.. Which MDB you have?

Comment: Some old piece of junk I can't even read the label on--What I'm looking for is a kernel module that acts to unload the kernel and execute the boot sector--similar to what a BIOS does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check [coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot) a Free Software project aimed at replacing the proprietary BIOS (firmware) found in most computers. coreboot performs a little bit of hardware initialization and then executes additional boot logic, called a payload.

**Wiki of coreboot [supported motherboards](http://www.coreboot.org/Supported_Motherboards).**

Extracted from [here](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot).

**EDIT**:

MCP55 chipset is [supported](http://www.coreboot.org/Supported_Chipsets_and_Devices). It could be that your chipset (*MCP61*) is supported.

Note that there is already support for your chipset **MCP61** in [flashrom](http://www.flashrom.org/Supported_hardware).

Specifically check this section of [coreboot wiki](http://www.coreboot.org/Developer_Manual#How_to_support_a_new_board)

I hope that I gave you some useful tips.

*Hopefully we are not off-topic in askubuntu ;)*

Comment: Unfortunately my motherboard is not supported, but a good software(kernel module) solution looks quite feasible or even already implemented, somewhere out of my lacking observational powers.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Could you list your motherboard to your question?

Comment: It's some unidentifiable Emachines OEM that I would have recognized had I seen it on the supported list

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Well but in general attaching your hardware specifications to your question could help (possibly) to get better answer(s).

Comment: Emachines el1200-06w with some unknown motherboard(really!), new 1 TB SATA hard disk(Seagate Barracuda), AMD athlon 64. [`dmidecode` output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1049808/) and [`lspci` output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1049813/)

Comment: Update: I am actually switching computers soon; If coreboot works in my new computer, then I'll accept.

Comment: I'm actually trying to use kexec as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the kexec-tools (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) by installing them using

```
sudo apt-get install kexec-tools
```

and allowing them to handling reboots on installation.
Try out a reboot, if your machine comes up without troubles, you're good to go.
But it doesn't exen reload grub, it reboots loading the latest kernel immediately.