# Reboot Ubuntu without going through the BIOS POST

Tags: 12.04, restart

Sometimes I am required to restart my Ubuntu machine and don't want to go through the BIOS then Grub. I remember that in windows we just need to hold down the Shift Key while clicking restart and trying the same procedure in Ubuntu without any success.

Comment: This is a duplicate! See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152661/warm-reboot-directly-to-grub

Comment: @Frantique No, I don't think my question is duplicate as the above link speaks about directly booting to Grub bypassing the BIOS and I am talking about bypassing all those thing BIOS and the GRUB too. I also want to restart from within my Ubuntu system might be with some modification and not making any changes to Firmware(Motherboard).

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include why you would want to restart the way you describe as opposed to doing a proper restart?

Comment: Ok, what about `sudo kill -9 -1`?

Comment: @Frantique I used your code and it instantly makes the Screen dark just like expanded terminal (CUI) with a frozen cursor and had to restart my PC pressing the reset button.

Answer (score 1):

On standard x86 PCs address 0x472 controls whether or not one does a cold or warm reboot. By writing 0x1234 to this address, the BIOS should do a warm reboot, and if zero is written to this address a cold reboot will occur.

This can be controlled with the kernel parameter reboot=w (warm) or reboot=c (cold).  So using sudo and your favourite editor, edit `/etc/default/grub` and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=w"
```

and save.  Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.  Hopefully, you should be doing warm reboots from now on.  I've not tested this, but the code is there in the kernel to support this, see `arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c` in the kernel source and how `reboot_type` controls the reboot.

Comment: lan king I have edit grub and then update but when I click restart it still goes through all the procedure bios, grub etc. and also ubuntu now restart immediately without waiting to close for any open application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the kexec-tools (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) by installing them using

```
sudo apt-get install kexec-tools
```

and allowing them to handling reboots on installation.
Try out a reboot, if your machine comes up without troubles, you're good to go.

Comment: This actually does not make reboots faster for me ( it takes longer to shut down and then kernel takes 7 seconds to boot as compared to less than 2 when using normal reboot), is that expected?

Comment: Absolutely not, for me it's just the same as a reboot minus the BIOS Time. I have only one idea, why that could be: A device has to be waited for (old hard disk, e.g. SCSI, ...) Anything special with the hardware?

Comment: No, a standard laptop, Thinkpad W530 by Lenovo. First it flickers during shutdown (very weird graphical effects) and then it takes much longer to boot:-/. I am using an EFI install, if that might make a difference.

Comment: @sup I also had devices, that made problems, one was an old laptop, that didn't lighten the display again after reboot. Another one failed  reactivating a modem/sim card slot. Sorry, no I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ha, I messed with systemd a bit (mainly to disable unneeded services to make it boot faster) and now it is quick enough (about two seconds, so reboot takes altogether like 7 seconds). However, it still flickers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jDkEEjb0qA&feature=youtu.be- I disabled plymouth (removed quit-splash from grub config) an the flicker is gone.